# What is Caché Object Script's method for passing parameters to a base constructor?

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems, intersystems-ensemble

What is Caché Object Script's method for passing parameters to a base constructor?

For example, in C# you would do the following:

```
public MyConstructor(string id) : base(id) { }
```

where `id` is the value you wish to pass to the base constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Do ##super(id)
```

super must be in lower case.